# 'Dynamic' use of variable in C?

Tags: c, function, replace

Hey there,
assuming I have the following function:

```
#define SIZE 100
double a[SIZE];
double b[SIZE];

double a_function(int index1, int index2)
{
    switch(index1)
    {
        case 1:
            return a[1]*a[2]*a[5]*a[3];
        case 2:
            return a[6]*cos(a[77])*exp(a[95]);
        // .............. MUCH MORE CASES 
        // ALWAYS USING ONLY VALUES OF ARRAY a
        case 100:
            return exp(a[20])*sin(a[21]);
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the following: `index2` is between 0 and `SIZE-1` and than I want to 'replace' every `a[ index2 ]` by using `b[ index2 ]` in EVERY case without changing the switch/case-construct. Further, a and b can't be modified, so they are read-only!

Short example on this:
  `a_function(2, index2)` for index2 != {6, 77, 95} -> returns `a[6]*cos(a[77])*exp(a[95]);`

`a_function(2, 6)` -> returns `b[6]*cos(a[77])*exp(a[95]);`

Any idea on how to do this?
Perhaps with some helping function or by using 'templates'?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to make a macro to do this

```
#define X(n) ((index2==n)?(b[n]):(a[n]))

double a_function(int index1, int index2)
{
   switch(index1)
    {
        case 1:
            return X(1)*X(2)*X(5)*X(3);
        case 2:
            return X(6)*cos(X(77))*exp(X(95));
        ...
        case 100:
           return exp(X(20))*sin(X(21));
   }
```

}

Comment: Ah thanks that looks pretty cool. But I just wonder how the performance would be of this, if I would integrate the macro quite often?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have

```
{
    for (int j=0; j<SIZE; ++j) {
        a_function(index1, j);
    }
}
```

So why not use

```
double c[SIZE];

double a_function(double c[], int index1)
{
    switch(index1)
    {
        case 1:
            return c(1)*c(2)*c(5)*c(3);
        ...
    }
}

{
    double c[SIZE];
    for (int i=SIZE; i--; ) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }

    for (int j=0; j<SIZE; ++j) {
        c[j] = b[j];
        ... = a_function(c, index1);
        c[j] = a[j];
    }
}
```

PS — Whatever method you use, your giant switch might be better implemented as a lookup table of function pointers.

```
typedef double (*transform_t)(double*);

double transform1(double* c) { return c[1]*c[2]*c[5]*c[3]; }
double transform2(double* c) { return c[6]*cos(c[77])*exp(c[95]); }
...
double transform100(double* c) { return exp(c[20])*sin(c[21]); }

transform_t transforms[100] = {
    transform1,
    transform2,
    ...
    transform100,
};


{
    double c[SIZE];
    for (int i=SIZE; i--; ) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }

    ...

    for (int j=0; j<SIZE; ++j) {
        c[j] = b[j];
        ... = (transforms[index1])(c);
        c[j] = a[j];
    }
}
```

**Update**: I just noticed "a and b can't be modified, so they are read-only!". Adjusted.

**Update**: Added suggestion for alternative to switch statement.

Comment: Thanks so far but I don't get the last three lines of code yet. Could you please explain them again..!? Thanks!

Comment: @Col Heather, I temporarily replace `a[index2]` with `b[index2]`. Then you can just use `a[]`. You said `a[]` can't be modified, so I made a copy of it that can be modified. As I specificed, this assumes that you call the function multiple times with the same arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
    #define SIZE 100
     double a[SIZE];
     double b[SIZE];

     double a_function(int index1, int index2)
     {
switch(index1)
{
    double *choice = (index2 != 6)?a:b;          <<< set choice
    case 1:
        return a[1]*a[2]*a[5]*a[3];               
    case 2:
        return choice[6]*cos(a[77])*exp(a[95]);   <<< use choice
    // .............. MUCH MORE CASES 
    // ALWAYS USING ONLY VALUES OF ARRAY a
    case 100:
        return exp(a[20])*sin(a[21]);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey there, sorry, I think you misunderstood my a little bit: 6 was just an example. `a_function(2, 95)` -> returns `a[6]*cos(a[77])*exp(b[95]);`

Comment: @lucas it's better to make the choice once, instead of doing it every time in the macro definition.

Comment: Than please show me how to do this correctly!? :-) Your example is, as I said, not what I asked for :(

Comment: i still do not understand your question -- you say you want to replace every occurrence of a[index2] with b[index2], but i do not see any occurrence of a[index2] in your code! in any case, what you want is to replace a[index2] by choice[index2] where 'choice' is set to either a or b, once, depending on your criterion. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I really don't know how to explain it better...That's why I added some examples :)